# 3 wire and 4 wire wiring configuration in PLC

Tags: adc, plc

I need some clarification on 3 and 4 wire connection.

1. In the 2/3/4 wire system, Is the PLC must to provide power to the transmitter or transmitter is powered by the external supply.?
   Please clarify on the above query. If you have any article on this please share to us.
   [image]
   Regards,
   Chitharanjan M

Comment: Chitharanjan - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to include the original source link for that image (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Type 3 applies power to the loop externally. Type 4 applies power to the loop internal to the transmitter.

This allows the loop cable to be unbroken. This results in better control over noise and interference for the loop.

I don’t have a reference. The ISA documentation should provide clarity.